# Infopath - print form to network printer

Tags: infopath, vsta

this seems like such a simple question, but is there a way to print a completed infopath form to a network printer using VSTA/VB?

I confirmed that Me.Print() in the click event of a button was working fine to print to the default printer on the users workstation, but how do I re-route the print job to a printer other than the default?

Answer (score 0):

Change to `Me.Print(true)` to show the standard Windows Print dialog where they can choose a printer and settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa944532(v=office.14).aspx